# Retrieving all elements of a database in a list (Hibernate)

Tags: database, hibernate

How can I retrieve all elements of a table using Hibernate? Currently I'm running a for cycle to get each of them and appending them to a list. Is there a more efficient way to do it?
Also with this method I have to hard-wire the number of elements in the list. How can I get **all** elements?

Content of my `HibernateUtil` class:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = initHibernateUtil();

    private static SessionFactory initHibernateUtil() {
        try {
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url",
                    "jdbc:sqlite://home/robb/Workspace/MyApplication/mydatabase.db");
            return config.configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

The method I'm using to retrieve the first 10 Products using Hibernate:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    products.add((Product) session.get(Product.class, i));
}
```

Comment: `@BatchSize` from `org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize`

Comment: @Zorglube you mean as annotation on the definition of the relative `@Entity`? But how would I write the for cycle in this case?

Comment: That just mean to Hibernate to load the entity by `@BatchSize`chunk. But I don't know if it's feet's your issue.